# How to use map for load from web service?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a web service (soap).I displayed some fields on labels (sales of branches etc) with branch ID(send branch ID to web service and display some fields)

There are latitude and longitude in my service.Every branch has lat.and long.I want to show branch on map when user enter branch ID for display some things.I dont have any idea for start.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}
```

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

try this